# Pasting Bold text into a doc after being taken form Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

So I've been working through a problem of pulling structured data from a spreadsheet and them using App Script to insert it into a Template Google Doc.

I have it working simply as concatenated strings, but I'm trying to do it with the BODY class so if I want to put the end product into Gmail it could be easier. Or if I want to retain table structure....

So, everything is fine and dandy, except for this one bit of code. I'm struggling with setBold. It's a weird syntax in that it's a boolean operation, right?

So here is what I have and it's pretty easy to grok I think:

```
    for(var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    var songName = String(dataArray[i][1]);
    var sWs = String(dataArray[i][2]);
    var pub =  String(dataArray[i][3]);
newText.editAsText().appendText('SONG NAME:'+ nLi).setBold(true);
newText.editAsText().appendText(songName + brk).setBold(false);
newText.editAsText().appendText('SONGWRITER(S):' + nLi);
```

But it's coming out as:

SONG NAME:

I have also tried this code:

```
newText.editAsText().setBold(true);
newText.editAsText().appendText('SONG NAME:'+ nLi);
newText.editAsText().setBold(true);
newText.editAsText().appendText(songName + brk);
newText.editAsText().appendText('SONGWRITER(S):' + nLi);
```

Thinking of the setBold as setting then unsetting a flag.

Neither worked.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using styles:

```
function addboldtext() {
  const doc=DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  const body=doc.getBody();
  const style1={};
    style1[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD]=true;
    style1[DocumentApp.Attribute.FOREGROUND_COLOR]='#000000';//you can add all of the attributes that you wish
  body.appendParagraph("This is text").setAttributes(style1)
}
```

Comment: This formatting is absurd. 



Interesting. I used:



`const hOne={};
    hOne[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD]=true;
    hOne[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 10;
const hTwo={};
    hTwo[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD]=false;
    hTwo[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 9;

newText.editAsText().appendText('SONG NAME:'+ nLi).setAttributes(hOne)
newText.editAsText().appendText(songName + brk).setAttributes(hTwo);
}       
body.replaceText("##XXXX##", newText.getText());`



I wonder if using getText strips it out. Maybe I should use another replacement

Comment: Hello @EzraGreene, is your comment the solution you implemented? If so, could you post it as an answer? Thanks :)

Comment: No, it's not. But I'd love some help reformatting it is, at a minimum, legible.

Comment: What do you mean by `reformating it` If you are suggest that formatting code in a comment is absured that's true.  But normally we would prefer that you put that sort or code in your question.

Comment: I don't even know what we're discussing anymore. 1. My code still doesn't work. 2. I can't properly format my comments well. Those two things are true. Beyond that, it's a muddle to me.

Comment: I can confirm @Cooper's solution works as expected.